# what is missing for DocumentNode function to show text in datagridview?

Tags: c#, string, foreach, datagridview, html-agility-pack

What i´m trying to do is to use the documentnode method to find a specific table from the internet and put it into datagridview. My code can be seen below:

`

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("xpath link")
       .Descendants("tr")
       .Where(tr=>tr.Elements("td").Count()>1)
       .Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim())
       .ToList();

foreach (var tables in table)
{ list.Add(tables.ToString());}

dataGridView1.DataSource = list
```

`

The result I get in the table is a list of numbers instead of text ([datagridview table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NInUg.png)). As I have tried to see it the text actually appears I changed the foreach with the following code:

`

```
foreach (var tables in table)
{
 list.Add(tables.ToString());
richTextBox1.Text += tables;
}
```

`

The result I get from the change is a string of the table in richTextBox1 but still a table of numbers in datagridview1 [richtextbox1 text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbfGG.png). This means I´m getting the right table from the internet and its being loaded correctly but i´m still missing something for the datagridview1 as I get a list of numbers instead of text that is being shown in richtextbox1. I followed this up by changing the DocumentNode function with removing parts in the .select part of the code and the datagridview1 stilled showed numbers (I added for example .ToString, .ToList() etc.).

What exactly have I missed in my code that makes this happen and should I have added something else to make it show the text instead of numbers?

Edit:
New code.

`

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(); 
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("td", typeof(int));

var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id=\"cr_cashflow\"]/div[2]/div/table")
.Descendants("tr")
.Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim())
.ToList();

foreach (var tables in table)
{
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { int.Parse(tables) });
}
dataGridView1.DataSource= dt1;
```

`

Comment: you configured `DataGridView` to show `Length` property (among others) from some class ... well and the class in your case is string and has only 1 property - `Length` ... and you get what you coded ... first you need to understand how binding works in `DataGridView` - way too broad for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("td",typeof(int));
var rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("xpath link")
       .Descendants("tr")
       .Where(tr=>tr.Elements("td").Count()>1)
       .Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim())
       .ToList();

foreach (var row in rows)
{ 
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { int.Parse(row)});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I have tried your suggestion but the foreach loop stops when it comes to the dt.rows.add line (i have also changed from dt to dt1 is it is what I named it). I have done some further exploration of the code and I believe I should change .Count() to something else, Do you have any suggestion for that? Apologies if it´s a bad question. I´m self learning all of this.

Comment: Your select is getting a string (text).  I assumed the text were numbers.  You may want to make it a string so it won't stop if data is not numbers.  You can also add for debugging in the foreach loop : Console.WriteLine(row) or add break point inside the foreach and hover over the variable row to see what it contains.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have done that and the string now shows with the breaking point but doesnt show up in the datagridview (added new code in the question) when I continue. I´m guessing the datagridview3.datasource is the wrong way to do it even though the "txt" in this case is the string I want to show in the table. Do you think I should use another way or have I missed something in my code with the transaction from string to the table view?

Comment: Do you have : dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1? It doesn't need to be in a for loop.  Which DGV are you using 1 or 3?  DataSource will load an entire table without the for loop.  You do not need strings.  DataSource will take one or more columns with different type object like string, int, DateTime.

Comment: Yes (I updated the code now). I have tried with your suggestion again and the code still jump to the catch(which is just a messagebox saying error). I´m using DGV 1, thanks for pointing that out. Ohh, ok I had misunderstood its capabilities then. That the reason I added your code again, since I guess the forloop still needs to be there for the data from "tables" to be added to dt1.

Comment: I'm not sure what code you are using.  What is posted doesn't look like my code.  You have to add a column to the DataTable.  And you have to add new object[] {}.  If you are getting an exception that means to column type and the data you are adding are not matching.  Best thing to do is in the column add change type to string.  the code above I used hundreds of times.

Comment: I´ve updated the code. Like I said the foreach code goes directly to the catch so not sure why the code doesnt get registered inside dt1

Comment: Try string : dt1.Columns.Add("td", typeof(string)) and dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { tables.ToString)});   This should display results and we should be able to find out why we do not have numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the help, finally worked. Wouldn´t be possible without your help.

Comment: Are all the rows number or are there empty cells.  I suspect there are empty cells that were causing exception.

Comment: Yes there is still empty cells. I was thinking that I could put in a if sequence that ignores them or takes them away from the table. Maybe there is a better way that makes sure the debugging is not stopped becuase of it?

Comment: Put an exception handler in the foreach loop where the parsing of int took place.  Then you can put back the code that used int.